# Microsoft Excel Conditionally Formatting Multiple Columns based on Adjacent Cell Text

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

[image: Screenshot of Conditional Formula Window]

Hello all, I have a question about how to apply a conditional format (cell color) based on (partial) text in the adjacent column. In the screenshot, you will see Column E has a list of zones. Listed in Column F are the sizes of each zone. While few of these zone names might repeat, there are sub-totals within the totals (groups of Column D). In order to make this visually easier to read (and automatically update the cell color if the list is updated), I want to set a cell color for the cells in Column E that contain the text "Sub Total", even within other text (which I believe is written as "* Sub Total *" (no spaces). I want this cell color to be applied to that row in BOTH Column E and Column F. I want to do the same thing for lines that read "Total". The conditional format expression I used for applying my cell color rule to "Total" was =$E13="Total", which worked (as you can see in the screenshot. When I made the same conditional formula =$E13="*Sub-Total", it did not work. I also wrote it with * Sub Total * to no avail. The 2nd formula in the screenshot, (Cell Value contains "Sub Total") does work and show that it recognizes the text, yet I can't get the conditional formula to work for both cells in the adjacent column. Where did I go wrong in my format? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use different formulas in conditional formatting. In an equality relation you cannot use wildcards. Two variants in the screenshot. Formatted area starts at the first row.
[image]
In the second case you can also omit `*` and even `ISNUMBER`, so it will suffice:

```
=SEARCH("Sub Total",$E1)
```

however the previous version is easier to understand.

Comment: Your formula seems to be saying: sum if the line contains the text "Sub Total", which is the end result I do want. My question though, is how to set a conditional format (cell highlight) for the cells in both Column B and Column C when Column B contains the desired text.

Comment: If you are to format columns `B:C` from the first row, you use e.g. `=SEARCH("Sub Total", $B1)`. `B` means column where you have your text, `1` is the first row to format.